# setCellValueFactory for a TableColumn in javafx doesnt input text for one value, but adds white space

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

So the main problem I'm getting is when trying to set `columnUUID.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("different")
            );` it wount populate the `columnPlayer.setCellValueFactory(
                new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("player")
            );` works.  If I set both with the value of "player" it populates both tables with those values.  If I set both methods with "different" it just adds blank text.  Changing "different" to a different value in both classes doesn't do anything.

```
package com.sandislandserv.rourke750.Gui;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.sandislandserv.rourke750.BetterAssociations;
import com.sandislandserv.rourke750.database.BaseValues;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
```

public class GuiController {

```
@FXML private TextField username;
@FXML private TextField domain;
@FXML private PasswordField password;
@FXML private AnchorPane pane;
@FXML private Button login;
@FXML private TableView<Person> listofPlayers;
@FXML private Label badLogin;
@FXML private TableColumn<Person, String> columnUUID;
@FXML private TableColumn<Person, String> columnPlayer;

private ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
public GuiController() {
}

public AnchorPane getPane(){
    return pane;
}

@FXML
public void Login(){
    data.clear();
    badLogin.setVisible(false);
    System.out.print(username.getText());
    System.out.print(password.getText());
    String players = getPlayers(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
    String[] player = players.split(" ");
    for (int x = 0; x < player.length; x=x+2){
        System.out.println(player[x] + " " + player[x+1]); // makes sure that both values are populated [for debugging]
        data.add(new Person(player[x], player[x+1])); 
    }
    columnUUID.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("different")
        );
    columnPlayer.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("player")
        );
    listofPlayers.getItems().setAll(data);
}

public String getPlayers(String username, String password){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Socket socket = new Socket(domain.getText().toString(), 25549);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out.println(username + " " + password);
        if (input.readLine().equals("BAD")) {
            badLogin.setVisible(true);
            return null;
        }
        out.println("Get All Player Info");
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null){
            if (line.equals("END")) break;
            builder.append(line + " ");
        }
        out.println("END");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

}
`

`
package com.sandislandserv.rourke750.Gui;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {

```
private StringProperty different;
private StringProperty player;

public Person(String player, String playerid) {
    this.player = new SimpleStringProperty(player);
    different = new SimpleStringProperty(playerid);
}

public String getPlayer(){
    return player.get();
}

public String getUUID(){
    return different.get();
}
```

}

```
`
```

Answer (score 1):

Rename your `getUUID` method to `getDifferent` and it should work. Even better, provide a `differentProperty` method that returns `different`.

The `PropertyValueFactory` looks for a method based on the name you give. More info in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html).